# Call a javascript function to refresh page when idle Error

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have the following `Javascript` codes in my `php` file called `qc.php` to refresh the page if idling more than 1 minute. This is working perfectly.

```js
//If idling for 1 minutes, page will refresh

var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 60; //in seconds. So every 1 minutes idling, page will refresh
var _idleSecondsTimer = null;
var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;

document.onclick = function() {
  _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};

document.onmousemove = function() {
  _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};

document.onkeypress = function() {
  _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};

_idleSecondsTimer = window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);

function CheckIdleTime() {
  _idleSecondsCounter++;
  var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
  if (oPanel)
    oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter) + "";
  if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
    window.clearInterval(_idleSecondsTimer);
    document.location.href = "qc.php";
  }
}
```

**Scenario**

I want to do this refreshing in many other pages and thus decided to make it as a function in a separate `javascript` file. Thus I created a function as follows and saved in another file called `func.js`

```js
function idlingTrigger(page) {
  //If idling for 1 minutes, page will refresh

  var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 60; //in seconds. So every 1 minutes idling, page will refresh
  var _idleSecondsTimer = null;
  var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;

  document.onclick = function() {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
  };

  document.onmousemove = function() {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
  };

  document.onkeypress = function() {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
  };

  _idleSecondsTimer = window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime(page), 1000);

}

function CheckIdleTime(page) {
  _idleSecondsCounter++;
  var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
  if (oPanel)
    oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter) + "";
  if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
    window.clearInterval(_idleSecondsTimer);
    document.location.href = page;
  }
}
```

Then I included `func.js` file in my `qc.php` file as follows

`<script src="func.js"></script>`

**Problem**

When I tried to call that function from `qc.php` as follows,

`idlingTrigger("qc.php");`

I am having `Uncaught ReferenceError` in my console

Does anyone know what is the problem here?

**Edit 1**

Realised that I am not passing the arguments between functions. So I edited my function as follows. Also changed all the private variable by removing `_`

```js
function idlingTrigger(page) {
  //If idling for 10 minutes, page will refresh

  var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 60; //in seconds. So every 10 minutes idling, page will refresh
  var idleSecondsTimer = null;
  var idleSecondsCounter = 0;

  document.onclick = function() {
    idleSecondsCounter = 0;
  };

  document.onmousemove = function() {
    idleSecondsCounter = 0;
  };

  document.onkeypress = function() {
    idleSecondsCounter = 0;
  };

  idleSecondsTimer = window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime(page, idleSecondsCounter, IDLE_TIMEOUT), 1000);

}

function CheckIdleTime(page, idleSecondsCounter, IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
  idleSecondsCounter++;
  var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
  if (oPanel)
    oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - idleSecondsCounter) + "";
  if (idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
    window.clearInterval(idleSecondsTimer);
    document.location.href = page;
  }
}
```

Now the console errors gone. But page doesn't seems refreshing. Any idea anyone?

**Edit 2**

I changed `func.js` file the following way and it is refreshing. But this way the page name is still static which is not what I need.

```js
//If idling for 1 minutes, page will refresh
var idleSecondsTimer = null;
var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 60; //in seconds. So every 1 minutes idling, page will refresh
var idleSecondsCounter = 0;

function idlingTrigger() {


  document.onclick = function() {
    idleSecondsCounter = 0;
  };

  document.onmousemove = function() {
    idleSecondsCounter = 0;
  };

  document.onkeypress = function() {
    idleSecondsCounter = 0;
  };

  idleSecondsTimer = window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);
}

function CheckIdleTime() {
  idleSecondsCounter++;
  var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
  if (oPanel)
    oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - idleSecondsCounter) + "";
  if (idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
    window.clearInterval(idleSecondsTimer);
    document.location.href = "qc.php";
  }
}
```

So what I noticed is, the moment I gave some argument to the function `CheckIdleTime`, the whole thing is not refreshing anymore. Anyone knows how to make the page name dynamic so that I can use this whole code as a common function for any page that I use?

Comment: My guess is that you're trying to call `idlingTrigger()` before you've loaded the script file. Post the HTML to be sure.

Comment: `idlingTrigger("qc.php")` is the last line of my code in that `qc.php` file and the `<script src="func.js"></script>` goes before that

Comment: put console inside your function see if thats getting printed

Comment: @Swati I didn't get what you mean exactly. May I know what you are asking to print out?

Comment: I mean to say put `console.log("in")` inside function see if that gets printed in your browser console when its called .

Comment: @Swati Yes. It is printing in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Modified it the following way. As you can see, I didn't pass any arguments into `CheckIdleTime`, instead use a global variable `page` in `qc.php` file. Then used that global `page` variable inside the function `CheckIdleTime`.

**Contents of func.js file**

```js
//If idling for 1 minutes, page will refresh
var idleSecondsTimer = null;
var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 60; //in seconds. So every 1 minutes idling, page will refresh
var idleSecondsCounter = 0;

function idlingTrigger() {

  document.onclick = function() {
    idleSecondsCounter = 0;
  };

  document.onmousemove = function() {
    idleSecondsCounter = 0;
  };

  document.onkeypress = function() {
    idleSecondsCounter = 0;
  };

  idleSecondsTimer = window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);
}

function CheckIdleTime() {

  idleSecondsCounter++;
  var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
  if (oPanel)
    oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - idleSecondsCounter) + "";
  if (idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
    window.clearInterval(idleSecondsTimer);
    document.location.href = page;
  }
}
```

Then in `qc.php`, added the following codes

```js
<script src="func.js"></script>  
var page = "qc.php"; //Pass any page name you want here and save it in the variable called `page`
idlingTrigger();
```

There might be an easy or elegant way. If someone has better way of doing please tell me how. Anyway the above method works